# Concatenate variables by commas in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

All this code works correctly. My question is for the variable lTest in the Messagebox, how can I display that list result concatenated by commas.

```
List<int> lNetworkIds = new List<int>();
Dictionary<DisplayDay, int> numDayOccurances = new Dictionary<DisplayDay, int>();

foreach (Proposal lDetail in this._Proposal.Details)
{
    if (!lNetworkIds.Contains(lDetail.NetworkId))
        lNetworkIds.Add(lDetail.NetworkId);
    if (!numDayOccurances.ContainsKey(lDetail.Day))
        numDayOccurances[lDetail.Day] = 0;
    numDayOccurances[lDetail.Day]++;
}

if (numDayOccurances.Count > 0)
{ 

    string lTest = "";
    foreach (DisplayDay myday in numDayOccurances.Keys)
    {

        lTest += myday.ToString();
    }

    MessageBox.Show(lTest);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lTest = string.Join(", ", numDayOccurances.Select(e=>e.Key.ToString()));
```

Comment: +1, not really sure why this has been downovted., I guess downvoters have reservations about `.Select(e=> e.Key.ToString())`, since it can be `numDayOccurances.Keys`

Comment: @Habib thanks, because it's not best solution. I missed out the overload accepting an `IEnumerable<T>` (just thought only `IEnumerable<string>` is valid).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the `foreach`, use:

```
string lTest = String.Join(",", numDayOccurances.Keys);
```

Comment: `Keys` is not IEnumerable<string>

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro really? remember that each element in the `Keys` is of type `DislayDay`

Comment: @KingKing, actually that's fine, coz `Join` takes `params object[]` as its joining parameters, and those will call out `ToString()` just fine.

Comment: @KingKing There is nothing wrong with this approach, each member of `Keys` will be implicitly converted to string. Your solution is similar to this though the conversion to string is more obvious.

Comment: @BeemerGuy thanks, actually I missed the overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @DGibbs That's because there is an overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>`, don't talked like as you did because it may confuse people.

Comment: @KingKing **I** might confuse people? This coming from the guy who claimed this solution was incorrect? Righto.

Comment: @DGibbs yes, it may confuse because it's not clear which overload is used.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use String.Join() for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx